# Keep order of many2many as insertion odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

I have two model: `A`, and `B`. `B` has a `many2many` field linked to `A` (named `x`). A include some objects with ids: `1,2,3,4`.

In `B`, I add items to `x` in order `3,2,4`, but it always reorders to `2,3,4`. I tried with `many2many_tag` widget but get the same results.

How can I keep the order of `x` like I have inserted.

Sorry for my bad English. Thanks

```
class A(models.Model):
        _name = 'a'
        name = fields.Char(string='Name')

    class B(models.Model):
        _name = 'b'
        x = fields.Many2many('a',string='x')
```

And the view

```
<record id="view_doc_generate" model="ir.ui.view">
       <field name="name">B</field>
         <field name="model">b</field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <form >
              <field name="x" mode="tree">
                  <tree>
                     <field name='name'/>
                  </tree
              </field>
         </form >
       </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the order you want `A` to be in by adding an `_order` attribute and using `write_date`:

```
class A(models.Model)
    _name='my_module.A'
    _order = "write_date asc"
```

That will bring the objects in the order you inserted them

Comment: Hi, Thank for your comment. But it does not work. When add items to x,  write_date is not changed. Moreover, if it work, it will reorder other existing B objects

Comment: Hmmm I don't think I fully understand your question then. Could you please add some code in your question, especially the part where you add items to `x`?